# Can Galactose be synthesized with photosynthesis?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

I know that galactose can be found in sugar beets and some gums so I thought plants could synthesize galactose but in my book the answer to the question "Which of these can be synthesized with photosynthesis in plants" was only fructose and glucose. Is that correct?

Comment: i suspect that this is only true if you expect the galactose to be made directly by carbon fixation from photosynthesis.  galactose and other sugars are often made by enzymes that convert from one type of sugar to another...

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but the question was asking direct synthesis by photosynthesis, so I think the question (or rather the answer to the question) is incorrect. Thanks for your answer

Comment: you ask, you learn...